# Error while reading data from web API using HTTP connector

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to pull data from web API using HTTP connector (of Azure Data Factory) and load into Azure Data Lake. I am successfully able to create pipeline using Copy Wizard but getting below error while running the pipeline.

Copy activity encountered a user error at Source side: ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedToReadHttpFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to read data from http source file.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.,Source=System,''Type=System.IO.IOException,Message=Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.,Source=System,'.

Thanks 
Nutan Patel

Comment: Could you please post more details codes about the your web api pull data method and post more about how you set your ADF? If you post more details information, it will be more easily for us to find the reason.

Comment: Hi Brando, thanks for your quick response. Here is the URL i am passing through HTTP connector https://{api key}:x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/{subdomain}/v1/employees/{employee id}/tables/jobInfo

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-http-connector#linked-service-properties), you could find:

```
The type property must be set to: Http.
```

So we couldn't use https as the http linked service, I suggest you could firstly changed your linked service's setting to enable http connected and test again.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I can not change my SaaS based application URL, It supports the only https

Comment: If you couldn't change the https to http, you couldn't use the ADF http connector. You need change the design.